# c# how to return empty object of user defined type?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a method that deserialize XML to Particular user defined type (Product Class).

```
public Class Product 
{
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
   public string SKU { get; set; }
   public string Att4 { get; set; }
   public string Att5 { get; set; }
}
```

This Method will accept XML Object and read it's properties and return a product class. I have a condition when the XML is empty I want to return  an empty object like this {}. Here is my deserialize method :

```
        public static Product DeserializeXmlAsParentProduct(object xml)
        {
            if (xml == DBNull.Value)
                return // I want to return {};
            var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml.ToString());
            var product = doc.Descendants("row").Select(pd => new Product
            {
                ID = GetValue<int>(pd.Element("ID")),
                ModelNumber = GetValue<string>(pd.Element("ModelNumber")),
                SKU = GetValue<string>(pd.Element("SKU"))
            })
            .ToList().FirstOrDefault();
            return product;
        }
```

My in put XML will look like this when a value is retrieved from the DB :

```
<root>
 <row>
  <ID>8</ID>
  <ModelNumber>GT</ModelNumber>
  <SKU>UR</SKU>
 <row/>
</root>
```

How Can I return empty object if the condition is met ?

Also If every thing went fine. It will return for me a product class with all the attributes.

```
{ID, ModelNumber, SKU, Att4, Att5}`
```

How can I use LINQ to return only the first three attributes only ? like this :

```
{ID, ModelNumber, SKU}
```

I was thinking of using dynamic object. Is there any Other way to achieve this?.

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: If you are doing a great deal of object deserialization, i recommend this method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz8csy73%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Also, I can't help but question the wisdom of storing values in a database as xml.

Comment: Actually I am not storing the values in DB as XML, But I retrieve them as XML. I am using this SQL Sever Option :                                         SELECT P.ID, P.ModelNumber, P.SKU FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, ROOT('root').

Comment: That is an entirely appropriate use of XML and is also a feature i did not know about! Thanks for educating me.

Comment: @Gusdor You are Well come.

Answer (score 2):

Using Linq to construct anonymous instances:

```
var anonResults = list.Select( p => new {p.ID, p.ModelNumber, p.SKU });
```

However, in this example you *cannot* `return` `anonResults`. Anonymous classes are only valid in the scope in which they are first declared.

If you *really* want to do this dynamically, javascript style, I would use [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

My recommendation is just return the full object. If you want to *restrict access* to `Att4` and `Att5`, consider implementing an interface on `Product` that only declares `ID`, `ModelNumber` and `SKU`:

```
public interface IProduct
{
    int ID{ get; set; }
    string ModelNumber { get; set; }
    string SKU { get; set; }
}

public Class Product : IProduct
{
   public int ID{ get; set; }
   public string ModelNumber { get; set; }
   public string SKU { get; set; }
   public string Att4 { get; set; }
   public string Att5 { get; set; }
}
```